Why timeout works differently when executed from terminal vs from a shell script file
I wanted to implement a unit testing shell script file that runs a command, compares the expected and actual output, and also add timeout constraints.
I used actual=$(timeout 2s ./bf --file ./test/inc-dec.bf) to capture the stdout. However I noticed that it hangs for around 2s.
To investigate the issue, I created a new script file called test.sh with the following content and ran it with ./test.sh command.
#! /bin/bash

timeout 2s ./bf

And it exitted with a 124 exit code (which is the exit code set when there's a timeout). Then I ran the same command from the terminal and it worked fine with the expected output and the correct exit code. The program I passed in should definitely terminate within a few milliseconds so the issue might not be with the actual time.
Here's the output of file bf if anyone is interested:
bf: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

Edit: This is the output of sudo strace -p $(pidof bf)
strace: Process 68264 attached
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=68263, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGTERM +++


Says stopped by SIGTTOU immediately
I'd like to know if there's a difference when executing the same command from terminal vs  a shell script file, or if I'm missing anything in general.

do bf expect something from STDIN?

bf doesn't expect input at this context. Just doing ./bf would output a help text. Just fyi bf is a brainfuck interpreter so there might be situations where an input is expected with ,.

when the bf hangs, use strace -p <pid> to see what it's doing.

sudo strace -p pidof bf
strace: Process 68264 attached
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=68263, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGTERM +++

So if I understood it right, SIGTTOU, SIGTTIN is sent to a process when it tries to read from / write to the terminal when it is not permitted? And I've read that timeout command doesn't allow read/write to terminal (or something like that). But it still worked fine when I ran the command as is, instead of executing it from the shell file. This is what confuses me.
